# unqualified id before a friend function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, friend

I am getting the error below:

```
..\src\test.cpp:17:20: error: expected unqualified-id before 'try'
         friend int try(Complex);
```

Please help and tell me why this code is producing errors:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex
{
private:
    int a, b;
public:
    showData()
    {   
        cout<<"\na= "<<a<<" b= "<<b;
    }
    Complex(int x, int y)
    { //constructer
        a = x;
        b = y;
    }
    friend int try(Complex);
    //friend function
};
int try(Complex c)
{   
    cout<<"You areworking in try now";
    cout<<"\noutput from friend fun : "<<c.a<<" "<<c.b;
}
int main()
{
    Complex c1(3, 4);
    try(c1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], visit the [help], read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Most importantly, code and error messages are text, so post them as such. No pictures, nor any links *to pictures*. It's less effort to copy and paste something than to grab a screen capture and upload it. It also makes your question *searchable*.

Comment: I strongly recommend against posting images. They are hard to search and harder to compile. Unless the picture is literally worth a thousand words or the question is about pixels, don't use them.

Comment: I suggest you also read the list of reasons in http://idownvotedbecau.se/. Some of them pertain to your post, and can help you ask better questions in the future.

Comment: Handy reading: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: Are you aware of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch ?

Comment: Please continue your good work on editing your question to show textual information directly instead of linking pictures.

Comment: Please take 5 minutes and learn how to format a question. It's not difficult. Really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's simplify the problem to a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem:

```
int try;
```

Not much code is required because [`try` is a reserved word](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). You cannot use `try` in a program without the compiler [expecting a `try/`catch` block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch).

Solution: Do not use `try` as an identifier. Instead use `try_func` or something that describes what is being tried.

Additional note: `showData()` needs a return type. Most likely it should be `void showData()`